# How to disable automatic migrations and create new columns/tables all by myself in code-first enviroment?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

First of all it needs to be clear that I never worked on a project that uses code first, and I inherited this project from another developer.

Right now I am trying to reproduce the error to post here in details, and the first error I am encountering is when I run a PMC command to add a migration, which gives me the following error:

> **Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending:** [202009221147053_wms,
> 202009221432482_wms_update1, 202009221554359_nsuadquirente,
> 202009292147548_TipoRastro, 202010061641251_NfeChanges,
> 202010221446470_Transferencia]
>
> **Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.**

Which I can't understand is how the program runs normally without errors if supposedly there are pending migrations. Probably these updates were done the way I am asking you guys how to do. I don't want to risk these "pending" migrations to ruin my SQL database, so I want to add new tables and columns manually. The thing is is not as simple as writing the classes and creating their corresponding tables/columns, so I am kind of lost now.

Answer (score 0):

Running the `update-database` command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio should fix this.

Also, applying a migration will not 'ruin your SQL database' - If you want to revert your database state, just undo the migration and your database should rollback to a previous state (assuming the rollback function of each migration has been properly written; sometimes Entity Framework is not able to auto-generate one and it's up to the programmer to write this).

You can revert a migration using the `update-database` command again but also providing a target migration argument:

```
Update-Database --TargetMigration OldMigrationName
```